# Override a method of Prestashop 1.7 module

Tags: module, overriding, prestashop-1.7

I want to override a simple line of code of the official module ps_featuredsearch of Prestashop 1.7.6.7.

The file is /modules/ps_facetedsearch/src/Hook/ProductSearch.php, method productSearchProvider (public) and line 56.

```
// OVERRIDE
// before: if ($query->getIdCategory()) {
   if ($query->getIdCategory() or $query->getIdManufacturer()) {
```

I've tried using the override folder without success.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not possible to override module classes directly.

The one way is to bumb version to for example 9.99 (to avoid updates), and take care of them manually, after your change to core of this module. It's not an ideal way, but it does the job.